# Django Multi-Conditional Statement

Tags: html, django, if-statement, conditional-statements, jinja2

I have the following code working in a Django HTML template. However, it’s quite repetitive. How can this code be simplified?

It translates to, "If you're not staff, you get to see nav.html. If you are staff, you only get to see nav.html if you're on these 4 pages."

```
{% if not request.user.is_staff %}
    {% include ‘nav.html’ %}
    {% else %}
        {% if request.get_full_path == ‘/one/’ %}
            {% include ‘nav.html’ %}
        {% if request.get_full_path == ‘/two/’ %}
            {% include ‘nav.html’ %}
        {% if request.get_full_path == ‘/three/’ %}
            {% include ‘nav.html’ %}
        {% if request.get_full_path == ‘/four/’ %}
            {% include ‘nav.html’ %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? You can check if a variable is in a certain list.

Answer (score 0):

From your view, you can send a list containing the paths for which to show nav.html. Something like,

```
allowed_paths = ['/one/', '/two/', '/three/', '/fourth/']
```

In your template, you can simply do,

```
{% if not request.user.is_staff or request.get_full_path in allowed_paths %}
   {% include 'nav.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: @user7358991 simple as well ;)